# how to prepare steps for below content?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `t_keyword_stat_ga` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `targeturl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `track_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `traffic_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `own_domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `medium` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pageviews` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bounces` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `traffic_date` (`traffic_date`),
  KEY `FK_keywordStatGA_targeturl` (`targeturl_id`,`traffic_date`),
  KEY `own_domain_id` (`own_domain_id`,`traffic_date`),
  KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`,`own_domain_id`,`traffic_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1707411331 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


 CREATE TABLE `t_keyword_conversion_ga` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `own_domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `traffic_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `targeturl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entrance` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transactions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_revenue` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal1completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal2completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal3completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal4completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal5completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal6completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal7completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal8completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal9completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal10completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal1Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal2Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal3Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal4Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal5Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal6Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal7Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal8Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal9Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal10Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `medium` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`),
  KEY `traffic_date` (`traffic_date`),
  KEY `own_domain_id` (`own_domain_id`,`traffic_date`),
  KEY `targeturl_id` (`targeturl_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=526248221 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i have a tables like _keyword_Stat_ga and t_keyword_Stat_conversion

1. I   Need  to  export  all data after October 31 2011 from the `t_keyword_Stat_ga`
   and `t_keyword_Stat_conversion` tables.
2. Import the backup into a ICE instance (for maximum compression) or an ARCHIVE table.
3. Need to drop the partitions in DB1 on the above tables through October 2011
4. We then need a before and after summary of disk usage